# Find Menu Item through Article Item?

Tags: articles, menu, navigation

I'm wondering if there's a way to see which Menu Item is associated with an Article.

I know this is easy from the Menu Item -> Article view, since Articles are assigned in Menu Items.

If I'm in an Article, is there a field or way for me to see its associated Menu Item?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] and perhaps introduce yourself and tell us about your Joomla journey in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to write some code to do it, but it wouldn't be hard.

To get a list of all the menuitems on your Joomla site you can do:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$sitemenu = $app->getMenu();
$menuitems = $sitemenu->getItems(array(), array());
```

Then you can cycle through the `$menuitems` examining the `query` property which is an array with values something like `array("option" => "com_content", "view" => "article", "id" => "123")`.

So you could write an administrator module to do what you want.

Inside the module look for the case where an administrator is editing an article, indicated by your URL parameters being something like `?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=123`. Then run the code above, look for where the `query` property has the appropriate values, and matches the `id` of the URL parameter, and then output the `title` for each matching menuitem.

You can find a guide to the menuitems API [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Menu_and_Menuitems_API_Guide), and on that page there is sample module code to get you started.